# cygwin sshd.exe & service randomly hang after a few days

Tags: windows-7, ssh, freeze, cygwin, sshd

I have cygwin and sshd installed, latest versions as of last month, on a Win7 Pro 64-bit box.  I can ssh in from a Linux box no trouble.  (It's identical to a setup I have on a Windows 2003 Server box that hasn't had this problem yet.)

Then, randomly, after some length of time, apparently usually days, when I try to ssh in, ssh just prints a blank line and the cursor blinks there until I Ctrl+C.

I remote into the Win7 box, and sshd.exe is running with normal CPU usage (0) in Task Manager.  I go to Services, and it says sshd is running.  I tell it to restart, and it fails to stop: the progress bar comes up, goes to about 40%, then crawls along, and eventually says it couldn't be stopped (but now it is stopped--I have the option to start.)  If I try to start, it tells me that it started and stopped immediately:

### Services

The CYGWIN sshd service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.  `OK`

This whole time sshd.exe is still in Task Manager.  At this point, I kill sshd.exe in Task Manager, and then I can go back to Services and can start sshd no problem, after which I can ssh in from Linux no problem.

I've seen various threads about similar-sounding situations from as far back as 2006, but no solutions besides increasing MaxSessions in /etc/sshd_config.  Only one user ssh's in, so I don't think MaxSessions needs increasing.

What causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the cause.  This is a crappy answer, but an unobtrusive (for my requirements) workaround is to schedule once a day to:

```
Taskkill /IM sshd.exe /F
net start "CYGWIN sshd"
```

Comment: Turns out it actually happens within 13 hours.  I'm going to schedule it to happen 30 minutes before I need it every day, but it would be much better if there were an actual fix, because if I happened to be doing something ad-hoc that ran into this schedule, it would fail.